# PHPExcel (and others) missing cell values while reading xlsx

Tags: excel, phpexcel, openxml, xlsx

I'm using different php libs to read clients orders from vast variety of file types.
Now I stuck a little.

I receive xlsx file (attached) which is probably being generated by some unknown software.
When I read it using PHPExcel (1.8.0) I get values only for cell containing numbers - at first look.

As we known xlsx is an archive container for some xml files.
When I dig a little into those xmls - I've learned that I'm getting values only for cell described in sheet file (xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml in this xlsx) worksheet->sheetData->row->c having attr "t" set to "n". Generally this means that values are in this very file. And tag "c" having attr "t" set to "s" - values are described in SharedStrings.xml. And PHPExcel is not getting them.

Or I'm doing something wrong?

Here is simple code:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$excel = $objReader->load($file);
$excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$data = $excel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);

print_r($data);
```

[Link to file](http://skiltrade.ru/hmm.xlsx)

Comment: I have no idea what is different about this file to any other xlsx file that PHPExcel is more than capable of reading, but generally speaking PHPExcel should have no problems reading values from shared strings.... it's what it's written to do.... is it possible to forward a copy of this file to find what is different and might be preventing PHPExcel from doing what it was specifically written to do

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you'd linked the file.... I'll take a look at it

Comment: I know, Mark, PHPExcel is doing a great job. But this time I guess it is a problem of a software which has generated this exact file. And I wanted to understand if I can do something with that (add something to xlsx archive or strip something) before claiming to client.

Comment: Just for other to understand - it is not a PHPExcel issue. Other libs getting same result. I'm trying to work around the exact file issue, maybe I'm not the only who face the problem

Comment: I can confirm that this particular file is problematic. `xlrd` (Python library) refuses to open it. I'm not an expert on Excel file formats, but the traceback implies that there is an attempt to reference the shared string table using an out-of-range index.

Comment: Yeap... Also: if you open it with MS Excel - it's ok. And resaving it increases filesize by 3 Kb adding some more subfolders and xml to archive structure. Looks like Excel is fixing file so it can be normally read by PHPExcel also.

Comment: @MarkBaker sorry to disturb. No luck with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First try to get highestRow by `getHighestRow()` then Use `rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestRow)` like this:-

```
$workingSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
$data = $workingSheet->rangeToArray('A1:Y'.$highestRow);
```

It will read all data from Excel and store into `$data`.

Comment: That is a basic snippet - I used it with no luck unortunately

Comment: It reads all data from all rows whose first cell is not empty, Otherwise it will not read that row. It may be the reason that you are not able to get all data from that sheet.

Comment: Thanks, but nope - all cells are filled with data.